# Border causes a gap in between border and content when zoomed out

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to have an outside div with a border and have divs inside with content that can have a dynamic height. Problem is that when zooming out, there are some random spaces that appear at the top( on chrome browser at 67%).

How can this be fixed? (the background color has to stay white, position absolute can not be used)
js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arminaspam/djpervLh/13/

````
    border-radius: 13px;
    box-shadow: -20px 20px #f6f5f7;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 266px;">
    <div style="background-color: white;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: 2px solid #0048c1;">
        <div style="
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #0048c1;">
            <div>
                Text that might be longer and take a dynamic amount of height in it
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: I think this is just a quirk with how elements are computed and painted at different zoom levels. I've noticed it in similar situations, especially when you're at a weird zoom level like 67% (which is actually 66.6666...%). See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000175/google-chrome-rendering-differences-when-zooming-in-out

Comment: In your case though, why do you even need the extra white div? Can't you just add a white border to your blue div?

Comment: I also am not seeing the point of having the div with the blue border and the white background. It seems like it is just over-complicating the code which then creates problems. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that div that can't be done with the blue div?

Comment: i am trying to do an accordion, which the div with the blue border should wrap. We only see the blue background div while not expanded, but when realising ti, it still causes weird gaps on top or sides.

Answer (score 5):

chrome rendenders broders in a strange way, to fix this i used 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #3d3691, -20px 20px 0 0 #f6f5f7 to act as a border and this doesnt bug out with differend zoom out values