# Sometimes small gap appears between child and parent in an underlined menu

Tags: css

I am working on a navigation with a bottom border. Active links are displayed with a second bottom border.

When I press refresh, sometimes there is a small gap between the two borders like on this screenshot. Why?

[image]

When I resize the window the gap is gone.
I have this issue in Chrome 97 on a mac. But I'm not sure if it doesn't occur in other browsers as well.

Does somebody can point me in the right direction?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li,
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li,
ul {
    margin: 0;
}

img{
   width:100%;
   height: auto;
 }

.projektmenu-wrap {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 98;
}

.projektmenu {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.projektmenu__item {
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.projektmenu__item--selected,
.projektmenu__item:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">

<nav class="projektmenu-wrap">
    <div class="scrollable-menu">
        <ul class="projektmenu">
              <li class="projektmenu__item projektmenu__item--selected">
                   <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
               </li>
               <li class="projektmenu__item ">
                    <a href="#">Dolor est</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

After some debugging i think the problem could be position: sticky.

**Edit:**

After some more debugging I realize that I forget something here, before the menu element there is an image with 100%width and auto height, maybe that could be the problem. I added it to the code above

After trying a lot of things, I have added some vw to the border, for the moment that is looking good. But it is hard to tell if it is the solution:

```
border-bottom: calc(3px + 0.1vw) solid #000
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, having such a double border solution is always prone to rendering issues, because at different zoom levels the browser renders the borders a bit different.

See also: [Google Chrome - Rendering differences when zooming in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000175/google-chrome-rendering-differences-when-zooming-in-out)

A solution / workaround for your example would be to define the border width in **relative units** (e.g. [rem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units)), which isn't linked to pixels but based on font sizes (e.g. the root element).

Try this out:

```js
.projektmenu__item--selected,
.projektmenu__item:hover {
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #000;  // alternative unit: em
    // or: using a mixture of fixed and relative units
    // border-bottom: calc(0.2rem + 3px) solid #000;
}
```

Also, although not required in this case, I would recommend you to use pseudo-elements like [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) for such markers in lists, it's basically what those are intended for.

Comment: thank you so much! I changed my code and it was looking good, but after some refrehes the gap appears again. I have edited my question, maybe it could be a hint?

Comment: I would experiment with relative units as I described in my answer. You could also use a mixture of fixed + relative sizes, like `border-bottom: calc(0.2rem + 3px) solid #000`. Again, it's hard to guarantee that double borders are rendered as expected in different browsers and zoom levels.

Comment: I updated my answer, if it serves well for your use case, please accept it. I think there is no better solution for this case.